# Facebook messenger bot quick replies occasionally don't appear on Android

Tags: facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm building a Facebook messenger bot and am finding that quick reply buttons occasionally don't appear on the Messenger client for Android -- I sometimes have to quickly swipe up and down for them to appear. This doesn't happen on the Messenger clients for iOS or the browser. Has anyone else noticed this problem, or found a workaround?

Comment: Can you open a bug report on this, please? 

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: happen many times but not all the time...I noticed that if I kill the messenger and reopen it - the problem fixed. like it is a bug in the messenger app for android. I also notice that when I open the messenger from the desktop and from the android the same time - the quick replies shown in the desktop but not in the android (both same wifi) so wtf?

Answer (score -1):

Did you check your internet settings? I think it is due to poor internet connectivity. And are you using Node.js to implement the messenger bot?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Node. I don't think it's the connectivity -- phone says connectivity is good, and it happens on a brand new phone as well as a previous phone of a different brand. It feels much more like a display bug on Facebook's end: there's no delay in the quick reply text appearing, but the buttons simply will not display without a quick up-and-down swipe. It seems to happen more often in quick replies that are preceded immediately by multiple messages or which follow a carousel, though it's not consistent.

Comment: I would suggest you to double check the syntax of send API. Could you please share the code snippet?